# Minimization of P(X=0) with E(X),$E(X^{2})$ and $E(X^{3})$

Tags: probability

We suppose that X is a nonnegative discrete variable.

We have $E(x)=1,E(X^{2})=2,E(X^{3})=5$.

Find the minimum value of $P(X=0)$.

I tried to prove that with Chebyshev ineaquality $P(X=0)\le\frac{Var(x)}{E(X)^{2}}$,

but i dont understand, how use the $E(X^{3})$

Comment: The way you've written it, the answer is 0.  However, I've seen at least two nearly identical questions asked recently, so I assume $X$ is supported in the integers.  If so, you might be able to find this exact question asked recently on here if you search for it.

Comment: yes X is in integer